# Does MATLAB have a strip function for strings?

Tags: string, matlab

Is there a simple function *f* such that

```
f(' hello, world! ' ) == 'hello, world!'
```

I can strip out the spaces (or any character for that matter) using regexes, but this seems like applying a hammer to the problem. I'd just like to know if there is something simple which I've missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use a hammer, simply use [`strtrim`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html).

From the documentation:

> S = strtrim(str) returns a copy of string str with all leading and
>   trailing white-space characters removed. A white-space character is
>   one for which the isspace function returns logical 1 (true).

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose there is a function to remove arbitrary characters from the edges of a string then?

Answer (score 5):

To remove the spaces on the side of the string, use the `strtrim` command.

Answer (score 1):

Since Matlab version 2016b, you can use the built-in [`strip()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strip.html) function.

For those who do not have the newer matlab version, here is my self-defined function, which also does not have the limitation of exact one char when strCharacter is passed in as strip()

```
         function result = trim(s,varargin)
            % Merge multiple spaces to single space in the middle
            % remove trailing/leading spaces
            % trim(s [, how [,chars]])
            %     s: a string 
            %     how: a num 1=left only; 
            %                2=right only; 
            %                3=left and right; 
            %                4 (default)=left and right and merge middle
            %     chars: if not given (default), space
            %              if given, remove consecutive character instead
            % 

            if nargin == 1
                how = 4;
                chars = ' ';
            elseif nargin == 2
                how = varargin{1};
                chars = ' ';
            elseif nargin == 3
                how = varargin{1};
                chars = varargin{2};
            end % end if nargin

            if strcmp(chars,' '), chars='\s'; end

            if how==1
                expression = sprintf('^(%s)+',chars);
            elseif how==2
                expression = sprintf('(%s)+$',chars);
            elseif how==3
                expression = sprintf('^(%s)+|(%s)+$',chars,chars);
            elseif how==4
                expression = sprintf('(?<=[(%s)])(%s)*|^(%s)+|(%s)+$',chars,chars,chars,chars);
            end % end if how

            result = regexprep(s, expression, '');
        end
```

Comment: amusing that the function is new and yet the documentation for it uses the obsolete `string` function